# How to append a image to the top of the box using css

Tags: jquery, css

Im having a menu which drop down when a div is hovered like this

http://www.flickr.com/photos/41695354@N08/5591505298/

I want to add a arrow at the top of that menu like this

http://www.flickr.com/photos/41695354@N08/5591505300/

How to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is, you can style your "Account" box, so that it is `position: relative`, so that inside this box, there is an arrow image, with `position: absolute`, and you can adjust the `top` and `left` to position the arrow image right at the top of "Account" box.

An absolute positioned element is absolute to the nearest ancestor element where the position is not `static`.  So `relative` counts.  Just make sure there is no `top` or `left` set for the "Account" box.